# PHP, Yii : Benefits and penalty to put an entire app within a try catch block?

Tags: php, performance, yii, try-catch

I am currently building a web app using Php's Yii framework.

I have a scenario where the app throws an exceptional in its initialization phase, just as the session data is about to be read ( currently from Redis). This exception occurs when my Redis server is down and my app just cannot communicate with Redis.

One working solution would be to have the entire app within a try catch block, in event of an unhandled exception, log it and show a lay man friendly error page.

More specifically:

Yii's app starts of in its main script, index.php, as

```
Yii::app()->run();
```

I could approach it as :

```
try {
    Yii::app()->run();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    header('Location: error.html');
}
```

My doubts are about how heavy would this try catch block make the entire application and how much of a performance penalty would this approach result in ?

Comment: If wouldn't make your application any "heavier" than it is already. It's just a try/catch block. When in doubt, benchmark with and without to see that there is no significant difference. Instead of the try/catch block you could also use `set_exception_handler` though.

Comment: +1 on using a custom exception handler. What I've done in the past is catch the exceptions with my custom handler and if they don't match the exception I'm interested in handling, pass it on up to the Yii exception handler instead. Works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

If no errors are thrown, anything within the catch block simply wouldn't run, and therefore won't make your application any heavier.

If errors are thrown and the catch block runs, it means the app isn't available, and therefore can not be made "heavier".

Any increase to the file size by adding a try-catch block will have negligible (or zero) effect as PHP is an interpreted scripting language.